# readCsvFile error: How to specify implicit value for evidence parameter of type

Tags: scala, apache-flink, scala-2.11, flink-batch

I am working in IntelliJ to create and test a machine learning model that will classify incoming data from a stream. I am working in Scala (2.11.8) and using the Flink framework (1.8.3). I am trying to read a csv file that contains my training data in columns with long, double, and boolean data types with the following lines:

```
val env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
val trainingDS = env.readCsvFile(./training.csv)(DataSet[(Long, Double, Boolean)])
```

The error I get is: "Unspecified value parameter evidence$2." This parameter corresponds to the TypeInformation parameter.

What change do I need to make to specify this parameter? My imports include:
import org.apache.flink.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._

Additional iformation:
**readCsvFile**[T : ClassTag : TypeInformation](filePath: String): DataSet[T]

Comment: Can you include the signature of the the `readCsvFile` method?

Comment: Sure, I just updated the question to include additional information.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that should be

```scala
val trainingDS = env.readCsvFile[(Long, Double, Boolean)]("./training.csv")
```